# Pytorch tensor multiplication with Float tensor giving wrong answer

Tags: pytorch

I am seeing some strange behavior when i multiply two pytorch tensors.

```py
x = torch.tensor([99397544.0])
y = torch.tensor([0.1])
x * y
```

This outputs

```
tensor([9939755.])
```

However, the answer should be `9939754.4`

Answer (score 2):

In default, the tensor dtype is `torch.float32` in pytorch. Change it to `torch.float64` will give the right result.

```py
x = torch.tensor([99397544.0], dtype=torch.float64)
y = torch.tensor([0.1], dtype=torch.float64)
x * y
# tensor([9939754.4000])
```

The mismatched result for `torch.float32` caused by rounding error if you do not have enough precision to calculate (represent) it.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)